# Как в комментарии ставить пометку с правильным решением?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, ответы

Присутствует символ тревоги и возможность ответить на свой вопрос. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не понятно как отметить комментарий с правильным решением?

Comment: Никак. Комментарии не предназначены для ответов. Можете попросить автора перенести ответ в ответ. Или сделать это сами, если он не против.

Comment: Или можете сами опубликовать ответ, если автор не хочет

Answer (score 7):

Довольно эпично выглядят ответы в комментариях ([раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12318/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/12319#comment53310_12318), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12318/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/12319#comment53311_12318)), о том, что так делать не стоит.

> [image: Никак. Комментарии не предназначены для ответов. Можете попросить автора перенести ответ в ответ. Или сделать это сами, если он не против. – Kromster Или можете сами опубликовать ответ, если автор не хочет – Алексей Шиманский]

Сделаю поблажку на то, что это было опубликовано на основном сайте до переноса вопроса. И воспользуюсь советом из второго комментария.

Не пишите ответы в секции комментариев. Ответ на вопрос должен быть в секции ответа. Механизма пометки комментария как ответа не существует. Можно только если сделать на него ссылку в опубликованном как ответ сообщении.

Comment: Не надо никаких поблажек - берите за основу смело! )

Comment: Ну, пример "как не надо" тоже пример :)